# Why use FormFactory in an event subscriber event?

Tags: symfony

Why do people use the FormFactory in an event subscriber event?

I currently have an event subscriber like so...

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FormEvent::PRE_SET_DATA => 'doSomething',
    );
}

public function doSomething(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();

    ... /// other stuff, see below /// ...
}
```

At present I am then using..

```
    $form->add('field', 'type', options);
```

But a lot of other developers use the form factory..

```
    $form->add($formFactory->createNamed('field', 'type', null, options);
```

Both seem to work so what is the reason for using the extra form factory object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `->add(name,type...)` only since [v2.2](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#220). So code written for older versions should use `$formFactory` to build instances of FormInterface

Comment: Ah cool. So as long as I don't care about backward compatibility I can forget the extra `$formFactory` stuff. Cheers.